# Mounting an NFS share in a docker container from a NAS

Tags: docker, mount

I have a docker container running sab and want my downloads to be placed in a mounted NFS share I have on the local machine.

Outside of the docker container, I have a NFS share in `/mnt/Plex` that was mounted using the IP address 192.168.1.50:/Plex

How can I put this mount in the docker container?

using this script `docker service create \ --mount 'type=volume,src=<VOLUME-NAME>,dst=<CONTAINER-PATH>,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=nfs,volume-opt=device=<nfs-server>:<nfs-path>,"volume-opt=o=addr=<nfs-address>,vers=4,soft,timeo=180,bg,tcp,rw"' --name myservice \ <IMAGE>`

Comment: If the NFS share is mounted on your host in `/mnt/Plex`, you can expose that inside your container with `docker run -v /mnt/Plex:/path/insode/volume ...`

Comment: What do you mean /path/insode/volume and how do I specify what Container and image to use?